# Collecting card details within the app on Telr Payment gateway

Tags: ios, swift, payment-gateway

I am integrating "Telr" payment gateway on my current app.I have read all docs part. My app will be collecting the card details (rather than using the hosted payment pages).This is the request i am making.If anybody has some demo or integrated Telr payment gateway, please feel free to reply.

```
let paramString: String = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
        "<mobile>" +
        "<store>\(12345)</store>" + "<key>somekey</key>" +
        "<device>" +
        "<type>\("iPhone6")</type>" +
        "<id>\(deviceId)</id>" +
        "<agent></agent>" +
        "<accept></accept>" +
        "</device>" +
        "<app>" +
        "<name>Telr_Payment_Demo</name>" +
        "<version>1.0</version>" +
        "<user>xyz.Demo</user>" +
        "<id>1234567</id>" +
        "</app>" +
        "<tran>" +
        "<test>12</test>" +
        "<type>paypage</type>" +
        "<class>moto</class>" +
        "<cartid>syste1075</cartid>" +
        "<description>this is demo on telr</description>" +
        "<currency>AED</currency>" +
        "<amount>\(9.80)</amount>" +
        "<ref>\("000000000001")</ref>" +
        "</tran>" +
        "<card>" +
        "<number>\("5555555555554444")</number>" +
        "<expiry>" +
        "<month>\(02)</month>" +
        "<year>\(2018)</year>" +
        "</expiry>" +
        "<cvv>\(123)</cvv>" +
        "</card>" +
        "<billing>" +
        "<name>" +
        "<title>\("fsfsfs")</title>" +
        "<first>\("First")</first>" +
        "<last>\("last")</last>" +
        "</name>\n" +
        "<address>" +
        "<line1>\("Kathmandu bazar")</line1>" +
        "<line2>\("address 6")</line2>" +
        "<line3>\("Near gausala")</line3>" +
        "<city>\("kathmandu")</city>" +
        "<region>\("Bagmati")</region>" +
        "<country>\("Nepal")</country>" +
        "<zip>\("977")</zip>" +
        "</address>" + 
        "<email>\("s*********@gmail.com")</email>" +
        "</billing>" + 
    "</mobile>"
```

I am getting following response from server

```
 <mobile>
 <webview>
 <start>https://secure.innovatepayments.com/gateway/webview_start.html? code=f1caa6ce6c23595b71dc00369</start>   
<close>https://secure.innovatepayments.com/gateway/webview_close.html</close>
<abort>https://secure.innovatepayments.com/gateway/webview_abort.html</abort>
<code>f1caa6ce6c23595b71dc00369</code>
</webview>
<trace>40008/1683846/595b7168dc</trace>
</mobile>
```

The first url will redirect to hosted payment pages card details view.I do not know what should i do with that response.[This is the payment integration guidelines for developer.](https://telr.com/support/knowledge-base/mobile-api-integration-guide/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs you linked to say:

> When a webview response is received, the App will need to direct the
>   customer to the URL given as the start address. The App should monitor
>   the progress of the webview, and once it reaches the URL provided as
>   the close address, it should close the web display and continue with
>   the transaction process.
>
> To complete the transaction, the App must now make a second request to
>   the gateway. This request includes will trigger the final
>   authorisation stage of the transaction, and return the authorisation
>   response. The request must be sent to:
>
> https://secure.innovatepayments.com/gateway/mobile_complete.xml
>   ...

so I would start with that and see what happens